# PowerShell 5 class: Import module needed for type

Tags: powershell, class, powershell-5.0, powershell-module, import-module

I have a written a PowerShell 5 class:

```
class ConnectionManager
{

  # Public Properties
  static [String] $SiteUrl
  static [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential] $Credentials
  static [SharePointPnP.PowerShell.Commands.Base.SPOnlineConnection] $Connection
  ...
}
```

The type "`SharePointPnP.PowerShell.Commands.Base.SPOnlineConnection`" is from a custom (installed module), named "SharePointPnPPowerShell2016"

My class is inside another module/file, called "connection.manager.psm1".

When I load this module to make use of this class, it returns me the following error:

```
> Import-Module connection.manager.psm1
At connection.manager.psm1:6 char:11
+   static [SharePointPnP.PowerShell.Commands.Base.SPOnlineConnection]  ...
+           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Unable to find type
[SharePointPnP.PowerShell.Commands.Base.SPOnlineConnection].
```

When I manually load the (PNP) module in the PowerShell session before loading my module it is loaded correctly and I can use it.

But I don't want to always have to manually load the other module first before I use my module. I tried to import the PNP-Module directly inside my module by adding:

```
Import-Module "SharePointPnPPowerShell2016"
```

at the beginning, before the class declaration, but it changes nothing, the error "Unable to find type" still appears.

Any ideas how to do this correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can fix this problem by using a [module manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/new-modulemanifest?view=powershell-5.1)

There is a "Required Module" and a "required Assembly" section you could use. This should handle loading the requirements (as long as they are installed) when you load your custom module, which holds the class.

Comment: You are right. I successfully tested it by using a module manifest which includes the following line:
RequiredModules = @('SharePointPnPPowerShell2016')
This led to the module being correctly loaded without an error. Only problem is, that I sometimes need version ...2016 and sometimes 2013, and don't want 2 code bases. But this is another issue I will sort out myself :-)

Comment: Glad I could help! Does the name work with wild cards like SharePoiuntPnPPowerShell201* ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have declared a class in a module, you cannot use it if you `Import-Module`; that only brings in cmdlets, functions, and aliases. Instead, your script should `Using module` the module; that will bring in the class as well as the other exported items.

(I actually misread the problem; this does not work to solve the querent's specific problem - but for a class that does not use classes from other modules, this will allow importing of classes from modules. The querent has found a known issue in PowerShell; see the comments for further information.)

Comment: It looks like this is not currently in PowerShell 5, but maybe come with PowerShell 6.1 - https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2074 or am I wrong?

Comment: Try `Using module "SharePointPnPPowerShell2015"` in your module.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not seem to work. I put "using module "SharePointPnPPowerShell2016" as the first line" (and this module exists), but when I load my module with "using modle" in powershell (5.0.10586.117) it says again "Unable to find type [SharePointPnP.PowerShell.Commands.Base.SPOnlineConnection]."

Comment: OK, this might very well be that issue that you've spotlighted from GitHub.

Comment: This doesn't work, I've also encountered this problem (and the issue on Github) in the past. Using a "caller" script where you first add the types (either through Add-Type or using Reflection) and then call your PS script which include your classes should work though...